# Keep X requests running in parallel until N requests completed

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm having trouble finding an appropriate construct for the given use case.

I have a function that for the given input string generates a `Single<String>`. This `Single` is a combination of multiple tasks that are expected to take up to half a minute, but I think this is not relevant to the question.

The behavior I am trying to achieve is having 5 of these tasks active in parallel with the goal of completing N tasks. Since the tasks are expensive not only time-wise, no excess tasks should be started that would be discarded later. It is not important to somehow merge the results of these tasks, I simply persist each result in `onSuccess`.

So basically my plan is to have a counter variable that starts at 0. Then, in a loop, generate 5 `Single`, increasing the counter by 5. Subscribe to them, `onComplete` increase the counter and `onTerminate` if `counter` < N, start another `Single`.

In the end, however, I lack a good way to keep track of the recursively generated `Single` objects, but I need to wait until N are finished.

Is there a construct available that would make this easy, or should I try to achieve this with counters or a list of `Disposable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flatMap()` operator takes an additional parameter which is the number of simultaneous subscriptions it maintains. Here is a test sample:

```
@Test
public void testStuff() throws Exception {
    Single<String> source;
    PublishSubject<String> src = PublishSubject.create();
    src
            .flatMap( s -> doStuff( s ).toObservable(), 5 )
            .subscribe( v -> { // process v
            } );
}

Single<String> doStuff( String subject ) {
    return Single.just( subject );
}
```

If `doStuff()` returns a `Single`, you have to convert it to an `Observable`, since that is what `flatMap()` works with.